# how to send sms programmatically in iphone 2.0

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, sms, iphone-sdk-2

I need to send email programmatically in iphone os 2.0.

some where i found

```
NSString *url = [NSString stringWithString: @"mailto:foo@example.com?cc=bar@example.com&subject=Greetings%20from%20Cupertino!&body=Wish%20you%20were%20here!"];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: [NSURL URLWithString: url]];
```

is this is code work on iphone os 2.0.

similarly I need to send sms in iphone 2.0 and make a call.

I found it is not possible in sending sms in iphone 2.0 and making call.

Is there any third party tools to send sms?

Comment: A quick search of this site will answer your question, it has been asked many, many times, always with the same answer: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[iphone]+send+sms

Comment: It looks like the best option will alienate all of MaheshBabu's pre iOS4.0 users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You **cannot send an SMS programmatically** under *any* version of iOS, ever.

Under iOS 2 and 3 you can present the SMS app with a `sms://` link and you can include the number to send it to, but that's it. You cannot include the message body, and no matter what you can **never** send the message. The user must send the message.

Under iOS 4 you can present a view controller with the number to send it to and the message body using `MFMessageComposeViewController`, but you still **cannot send the message**. The user can tap the send button, but that's it.

Apple specifically protects iPhone owners from SMS messages being sent without their knowledge and approval.

Comment: Is there a private API we can use? I'm not planning on submitting my app.

Comment: @Sam Googling provided this site, which likely has the info in the Messages area: https://github.com/kennytm/iphone-private-frameworks

Answer (score 0):

To make a call from your app call this line:

```
[[UIApplication application] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel://THE_TELEPHONE_NUMBER"]];
```

Remember this won't work in the Simulator and you may want to check if the device is an iPod or iPad before calling! I also tend to show a `UIAlertView` asking the user if they actually want to call the number as this can be very annoying if they didn't mean it.

For SMS: Check out this [How to programmatically send SMS on the iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10848/how-to-programmatically-send-sms-on-the-iphone)

Comment: i think it is not work in iphone 2.0 it works after 3.2...some one has  told here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4582327/how-to-make-a-call-programmatically

Comment: Hmm, well I haven't used iphone 2.0 for a very long time. I can guarantee that I had openURL working with 2.2.1 but I do not know before this.

Comment: Why are you using 2.0 anyway? Do you plan on distributing this as I'm pretty sure you won't get very far down the official route. Even Ad Hoc distribution (I think) has to be built with 3.0 as a minimum.

Comment: i need to support all the oses that available in market,that's the reason

Comment: Well unless there is a specific reason you want to support iPhone os 2.0 you might as well drop it. How do you even plan to build with support for it? With the latest versions of the SDK (4.0 onwards) you cannot even build the deployment target for 2.0 - afaik 3.0 is the earliest a new build can support.

Comment: Also, I don't have any stats to back this up, but I would say that most users are at OS 3.0 and above.