# How do you make a call from your app?

Tags: iphone, ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make a call programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4582327/how-to-make-a-call-programmatically)

How can you call from your app? Where your app supplies the name and number to call and it calls it through the phones calling app? And if not supplying the name can you save it to the contacts through your app and then trigger a call to it?

any help is appreciated.

Comment: @BoltClock Depending on iOS that answer may or may not be valid.

Comment: @Shahzeb: I don't understand your comment. That answer has been valid for all versions of the iOS SDK on the iPhone.

Comment: @BoltClock May be I am wrong , my understanding is that answer is only valid of older versions e.g 3.2 . I will try it out and get back. Thanks for replying though.