# How to check if device can make a phone call (iOS 8)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, ios8

On iOS <8 you could use function `- (BOOL)canOpenURL:(NSURL *)url`.

On iOS 8 this function returns `YES`, even on iPad. I guess it's connected with calling over wi-fi (or another new functionality), but my iPad cannot make phone calls. Anyone know better way to detect that capability?

Comment: What's your end goal here? Are you trying to check if something is an iPhone? And how are you calling `canOpenURL:`?

Comment: No, I need to check whether device has this capability to hide phone button if user cannot use it. Or show appropriate message.

I'm calling it that way:
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel://"]]

Comment: FYI - I asked this on the [Apple Developer Forums](https://devforums.apple.com/message/1039439#1039439) a while ago and didn't get a good answer.

Comment: FWIW: Here's the behavior I've observed: When I have Continuity setup and iPad can make calls via my local iPhone, tel: links work and complete the call. This can be done either within a web browser (an HTML tel: url) or with openUrl:. If Continuity is not setup, HTML tel: links launch Facetime but then nothing happens. openUrl: called as, say, the result of a button tap, just doesn't do anything at all.  I'm also hoping for a way to check that the user can/can't perform this action based on their Continuity status.

Comment: Hi, @MaciejKozieł , have you found any solution? I have the same issue and this iOS behavior is still in the Apple's latest iOS versions.

Comment: If you get MCC/MNC you should be able to place a call (there is a valid SIM present and device is inside a cellular service range)... https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CTCarrier/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/CTCarrier

Answer (score 16):

Ok, so I just encountered the same problem. Seems like iPad and iPod return YES value for canOpenURL method. Please see my answer below since this worked for me. I had a custom collection view cell and that is why had this code in my awakeFromNib file. However, you should write this code in ViewDidLoad of that perticular viewController.

**Make sure to include *"CoreTelephony.Framework"* in your project.**

Include below files in the view controller:

```
 #import <CoreTelephony/CTTelephonyNetworkInfo.h>
 #import <CoreTelephony/CTCarrier.h>

    - (void)awakeFromNib {
    // Initialization code

    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel://"]]) {
        // Check if iOS Device supports phone calls
        CTTelephonyNetworkInfo *netInfo = [[CTTelephonyNetworkInfo alloc] init];
        CTCarrier *carrier = [netInfo subscriberCellularProvider];
        NSString *mnc = [carrier mobileNetworkCode];
        // User will get an alert error when they will try to make a phone call in airplane mode.
        if (([mnc length] == 0)) {
            // Device cannot place a call at this time.  SIM might be removed.
        } else {
            // iOS Device is capable for making calls
        }
    } else {
        // iOS Device is not capable for making calls
    }



    if ( ! [[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"sms:"]]) {
       // iOS Device is not capable to send SMS messages. 
    }
}
```

Comment: Are these private API?

Comment: Please note the [mnc isEqualToString:@"65535"] check employed here http://stackoverflow.com/a/11595365/1277350

Comment: Also, I suspect data SIMs in iPads will give a false positive, so I suggest adding a check for UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad

Comment: @LordParsley - *canOpenURL* will give false if the iPad has data sim right

Answer (score -4):

You could just see if it's an iPhone.  And possibly use this in conjunction with `- (BOOL)canOpenURL:(NSURL *)url`.  That way you avoiding devices that obviously can't make a cellular phone call.

```
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] model] isEqualToString:@"iPhone"] ) {
     // Make Phone Call
}
```

Comment: This is not correct solution. Phone calls are also possible on iPad.

Comment: @MaciejKozieł, I don't think that's what he was asking. Sounded to me like he was trying to discriminate against the iPad.  He mentioned that - (BOOL)canOpenURL:(NSURL *)url was returning YES on his iPad, but he didn't want that even if it could call over wifi.

Comment: First, it is my question. Second, if question is not clear to you, please read comments.

Comment: @MaciejKozieł, Sorry, didn't realize it was your question. In several of my apps I need to show/hide a phone button based on the ability to make a phone call.  My users complained when the phone button was available on an iPad.  Even after reading your comments it sounded like you were dissatisfied with - (BOOL)canOpenURL: returning YES on an iPad.  So I offered what made my users happy.  Good luck.

Comment: Problem is, actually there seems to be no way to determine whether device can make phone call. I don't want to use hacks on that. Furthermore, I'd like to present phone button on iPad, when phone calls are possible for that user. Thanks.

Comment: @MaciejKozieł Can you please describe the hardware where an iPad is able to make phone calls as per your requirements?