# iPod Touch canOpenURL of type tel://

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios8

On an iPod Touch running iOS 8.0 (12A365), `canOpenURL:` returns `YES` for `tel://` URL schemes.

Also, `openURL:` returns nil, **after a 5 - 10 second delay**.

```
UIApplication *application = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"tel://"];

if ([application canOpenURL:url])
{
    [application openURL:url];
}
```

Anyone know why `canOpenURL:` doesn't return `NO` for iPod? The facetime URL scheme is different ('facetime://') so in theory it should return `NO`.

Unfortunately I don't have an iPod with iOS7 to test, so I can't isolate the problem to only iOS8.

Comment: At a wild stab in the dark could it be that because you can make wireless calls now? This is just a wild guess here is an article on wireless calling for iOS8 http://appleinsider.com/articles/14/07/07/apple-activates-wi-fi-calling-for-t-mobile-iphones-with-latest-ios-8-beta

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25873240/how-to-check-if-device-can-make-a-phone-call-ios-8

Comment: It seems that the reason is [continuity](https://www.apple.com/ios/whats-new/continuity/). Some guys use carrier check like this:
`[[CTTelephonyNetworkInfo alloc] init].subscriberCellularProvider.isoCountryCode != nil;`
but I'm unsure if this will help with continuity.

Answer (score 1):

Hm I'm not sure whether I'm being helpful here as I don't own an iPod to test it but on Mac you can open a URL with a `tel://` scheme too which launches FaceTime. This can call via a nearby iPhone any phone number.

I don't know whether this is the case for the iPod models too though.