# Making calls on iPhone/iPod/iPad

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, ipod

I have some problems with the application that I'm woking on. At some point the user makes a phone call, and if it uses an iPhone the call will be made otherwise a message will be displayed when it uses other device.The problem is that on iOS 8 (all versions) a non-iPhone device can actually make a phone call.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:phoneNumberToCall]]
```

I use this method to check if the phone call can be made and the method returns true on non-Iphone device with iOS 8, but works perfect on previous versions of iOS(6-7.1). Any idea how it could be solved or why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every iOS 8 device has the FaceTime App which now provides the power to call anyone your iPhone can call.

[It's called continuity](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204681)

The user has to allow this on his iPhone in Settings.app under "FaceTime" -> "iPhone Cellular Calls"

Answer (score 2):

Same question here : [iPod Touch canOpenURL of type tel://](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25942491/ipod-touch-canopenurl-of-type-tel)

It seems that on iOS 8 you can make wireless calls, and that's why that method returns true.