# Call Functionality not work properly in iPad

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad

I have implement call function in my app. Call functionality work properly in iPhone but not work properly in iPad. When we press call button in iPad then call alert view dismiss but no functionality execute.

Comment: what iOS are you targeting on the iPad?

Comment: @MuhammadAsif check first whether in iPad Sim service available or not

Comment: @Mack how we check  iPad Sim service available or not

Comment: @MuhammadAsif simply try this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/30335594/1308632

Answer (score 0):

You cannot make a call on iPad.

Reference link: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5968677?tstart=0

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You have to check that call feature is enable or not in device

```
NSURL *phoneUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"123456789"];
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:phoneUrl]) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:phoneUrl];
}
else{
    NSLog(@"Call facility is not available!");
}
```